# I want to upload an excel into asp.net mvc application where excel contains Mathematical Equation and some Images

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to upload an excel into asp.net mvc application where excel contains Mathematical Equation and some Images. How to do it.Basically this application is online exam system for those student who preparing for entrance exam for IIT, NEET Exam.Here i am attaching the screen shot of excel which i have to upload.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXpkb.png)

Comment: what you actually do with the excel file? any processing? if yes, Jay Velasco answer is worth to check. is no processing are needed, you are looking a file upload.

Comment: Just to note, the tools mention below can read a file as well. For analyzing images you might be better off using an OCR tool - which Aspose also provides.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a question that is answerable?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a parsing tool:

SpreadsheetGear, Interop, Aspose, EPPlus (Free)

Interop is free, you parse the objects inside the spreadsheet.

EPPlus might be best since it manages the objects for you.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260087/add-what-types-of-questions-should-i-avoid-answering-to-the-help-center) before attempting to answer more questions.